# why sometimes mingw makefile error occurs while building a program in cpp?

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, mingw32

sometimes when i try to build a cpp program "mingw32-make.exe *** all error 1" error occurs and error goes away when you rebuild the program although it does not happens every time. i use gcc++ compiler on codelite.
here is the full build error i get:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j8 
SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  Makefile
"----------Building project:[ lab1 - Debug ]----------"
The system cannot find the path specified.
mingw32-make.exe: *** [All] Error 1
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
====1 errors, 0 warnings====*
```

would be grateful if someone could help me fixing this.

Comment: Please format your question properly.  For examples of code and output you can indent the lines with 4 spaces to get a monotype block.  This also preserves newlines etc. so the output is not wrapped.

Comment: This typically happens when the file that can't be found is created/updated as a side effect of some other rule.  `make` doesn't know how to make it but one of the other jobs running in parallel (you specify `-j8`) creates it so the next time you try a build everything 'appears' to work just fine.  Difficult to say any more without seeing the `makefile`, error message(s), directory structure etc.